# Using vb.net Count all occurrences of vbCrLf in TextBox

Tags: vb.net, textbox, counter

I have a TextBox that I am trying to count all the occurrences of `vbCrLf`.

The counting is working, the issue is every time a `vbCrLf` is issued I would like to subtract 33 from some Integer.

The code as written now only subtracts the number of `vbCrLf`, NOT the number + 33.

**Question is how to subtract 33 every time the Enter Key is pressed and a vbCrLf is issued ?**

I have posted Updated Code The Question Was Answered and Issues **SOLVED**
I have also added additional code that enhances the management of the TextBox
You will need these Imports
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

```
Public Class frmThree
Dim path As String = "C:/Users/Me/source/repos/TestForms/TestForms/Resource/"
Dim total As Integer
Dim vbLfTotal As Integer
Dim chrPermited As Integer = 333 'chrPermited

Private Sub btnBack_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBack.Click
    Me.Close()
    frmOne.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub tbHaveOne_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tbHaveOne.TextChanged
    Dim spaceCount, letterCount, carReturn As Integer
    spaceCount = 0
    letterCount = 0
    carReturn = 0

    Dim str As String = tbHaveOne.Text
    For Each chr As Char In str
        If chr = vbLf Then
            carReturn += 1
        ElseIf Char.IsLetterOrDigit(chr) Then
            letterCount += 1
        ElseIf Char.IsWhiteSpace(chr) Then
            spaceCount += 1
        End If
    Next

    vbLfTotal = carReturn * 29

    total = chrPermited - letterCount - spaceCount - vbLfTotal

    tbHaveTwo.ForeColor = Color.Black
    tbHaveTwo.Text = total & " More Character Can Be Entered"

    While total < 10
        tbHaveTwo.Clear()
        tbHaveTwo.ForeColor = Color.Red
        tbHaveTwo.Text = "Only " & total & " More Character Can Be Entered"
        Exit While
    End While

    If total = 5 Then
        PlaySystemSound()
    End If

    If total < 1 Then
        tbHaveTwo.Clear()
        tbHaveTwo.Text = "No More Data Entry" & total
        Call ansQ()
    End If
End Sub
Sub PlaySystemSound()
    My.Computer.Audio.PlaySystemSound(
    System.Media.SystemSounds.Hand)
End Sub
Public Sub ansQ()
    Const Msg As String = "YES Save Data" + vbCrLf + vbNewLine + "NO CANCEL"
    Const Title As String = "Save or Exit"
    Const Style = vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton2
    Dim result = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title)
    If result = vbYes Then
        Call writeDATA()
    ElseIf result = vbNo Then
        'tbHaveOne.ReadOnly = True
        'tbHaveOne.Enabled = False
        tbHaveTwo.Text = "NO Was Selected"
        'result = 0
    End If
    End Sub

Public Shared Sub tbHaveOne_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles tbHaveOne.KeyDown
    'NOTE this Sub is Shared It seems to run all the time like a listener
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter And frmThree.total < 40 Then
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `vbCrLf` is a new line - so `Dim count = tbHaveOne.Lines.Length`

Comment: @Fabio, the drawback with that is that `Lines` creates a new array every time you get it. If you do that on the `TextChanged` event then there's a lot of work being done for little result. Of course, the code posted does a lot of work on every `TextChanged` event too. If the desire is to do something every time a particular key is pressed then surely the `KeyPress` event or perhaps `KeyDown` should be the event being handled. Of course, you have to allow for deleting, backspacing and pasting too. This problem requires some consideration to be handled as efficiently as possible.

Comment: @Fabio I am not sure where to post your code I did just notice this line of code seems real wrong carreturn = (rex.Matches(tbHaveOne.Text).Count).ToString() Why convert this to a String when carreturn is and Integer

Comment: @jmcilhinney NO PASTING but I chose TextChange to avoid issues with backspacing found your blog and your wish list Are you still off grid?

Comment: It can certainly be done on `TextChanged` but the problem is that you're processing the entire `Text` every time, which is not very efficient. If you keep track of the caret position and the characters on either side of it then you can determine whether a line break was removed on a delete or backspace. You'd also need to consider when text was selected and all deleted. The logic is a bit more complex but the code is more efficient.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Well I agree it needs a lot of consideration as the plan is to add a spell checker to review the text I did get a kind of fix with this change carT = carreturn * 33 I plan to limit the TextBox to 8 lines of text each line is 34 characters long Thanks for the suggestions Backspace adds the value back to total count with the change!

Comment: @Vector, no you just use `Dim countOfVbCrLf = tbHaveOne.Lines.Length`, without Regex or anything else.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, with `Lines` you will get code working, next step would be to optimize it. We don't know how big text can be in Op's case. For max 10 lines I wouldn't bother with optimization, with hundreds - maybe based on how this affect user experience.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, on other side we don't know how result will be used. If result is used once in some action after user stop typing, then I would move calculation to  one of `Leave` or `Validated` or `LostFocus` events - then in this case I can use `Lines` because whole text will be "processed"  anyway.

Comment: @Fabio, if you were going to use `Lines` then it would be `.Lines.Length - 1` to get the number of line breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a lot of great Discussion and Fixed Answers on this question
One of the questions in the discussion was how to handle punctuation and special characters
We would like to offer this code as a way to manage both punctuation and special characters

```
    Dim spaceCount, letterCount, carReturn, punCount, syCount As Integer
    spaceCount = 0
    letterCount = 0
    carReturn = 0
    punCount = 0
    syCount = 0
    Dim str As String = tbHaveOne.Text
    For Each chr As Char In str
        If chr = vbLf Then
            carReturn += 1
        ElseIf Char.IsLetterOrDigit(chr) Then
            letterCount += 1
        ElseIf Char.IsWhiteSpace(chr) Then
            spaceCount += 1
        ElseIf Char.IsPunctuation(chr) Then
            punCount += 1
        ElseIf Char.IsSymbol(chr) Then
            syCount += 1
        End If
    Next

    vbLfTotal = carReturn * 29
    total = chrPermited - letterCount - spaceCount - vbLfTotal - punCount - syCount
    tbHaveTwo.ForeColor = Color.Black
    tbHaveTwo.Text = total & " More Character Can Be Entered"
```

Comment: @James_Duh Thanks we were looking at REGEX but did not like the idea this will deal with most of the text I am still wondering how the spell checker will interact with the TextChanged NOT sure it will interface with KeyPress or KeyDown ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't check if the current character is vbcrlf because CRLF is two characters. Just check for the LF, this way if you ever use the logic on a file prepared by a unix system, it still works (unix has LF, Windows has CRLF)

```
Private Sub tbHaveOne_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tbHaveOne.TextChanged
    Dim spaceCount = 0
    Dim letterCount = 0
    Dim lineCount = 0

    For Each c As Char In tbHaveOne.Text
        If c = vbLf Then
            lineCount += 1
        ElseIf Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) Then
            letterCount += 1
        ElseIf Char.IsWhiteSpace(c) Then
            spaceCount += 1
        End If
    Next c

    someInteger -= (lineCount * 33)
```

The System.Char has static methods that check characters are in certain Unicode ranges - for your letter count you were counting anything that wasn't a space, including carriage returns, punctuation and other things that aren't letters, as letters. You're free to carry on doing that if you want but it'll maybe lead to a bit of a confusing count if you triple count the newlines

> The counting is working the issue is every time a vbCrLf is issued I would like to subtract 33 from some Integer
>   The code as written now only subtracts the number of vbCrLf NOT the number + 33

I didn't quite get this. You say you want to subtract 33 every time there is a new line, which is what I've done. The second sentence reads like the requirement is to subtract the (number of new lines + 33) from someInteger. If this is what you want to do, change the * on the last line to +

> Question is how to subtract 33 every time the Enter Key is pressed and a vbCrLf is issued ?

This is a different thing entirely to "count all occurrences of"; it isn't to do with counting the lines in a textbox, and you can't do it from such code. Counting the number of times the user has ever pressed enter in a textbox needs a hook to the event raised when a user pressed a key while the box had focus. Add a handler for the KeyPress or KeyDown event:

```
Private Sub tbHaveOne_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles tbHaveOne.KeyPress 'KeyEventArgs for KeyDown event

    If e.KeyChar = vbCr Then 'use e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter in KeyDown event
        someInteger -= 33
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Where I got in trouble is I did not know how to write your If Then Else statement The TextBox has no scroll bars and is limited to XXX Characters I did keep linewrap because of this limit of X Char I wanted to subtract 33 Characters every time the Enter Key was pressed YEP needed to multiply not add  Will test your code I am sure it will work Thanks For the Detailed Answer

Comment: Fixed a bug, thanks to a note from JQSOFT. Make sure you take the latest code

Comment: Thanks I was about to tell you I could not get this working also It needs to be ElseIf Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) Then

Answer (score 2):

The `TextBox.Lines.Count` returns the count of the lines separated by newline characters (*ControlChars.NewLine* or *Environment.NewLine* when you hit the *Enter* key.) and not the count of the word-wrapped lines in a multiline TextBox. If you set the [WordWrap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.wordwrap?view=netcore-3.1) property to `False` you will see the difference. See the [TextBoxBase.Lines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines?view=netcore-3.1#remarks) remarks section.

You could call the [SendMessage](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SendMessage.html) method and the `EM_GETLINECOUNT` message if you need to get the count of the lines regardless whether they are word-wrapped or separated new lines:

```vb
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Private Const EM_GETLINECOUNT As UInteger = &HBA

<DllImport("user32.dll")>
Private Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr,
                                ByVal msg As Integer,
                                ByVal wp As IntPtr,
                                ByVal lp As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Function

Private Sub PrintCounts()
    Dim c = tbHaveOne.Text.
        Aggregate(New With {
        .WhiteSpaces = 0, .Lf = 0, .NewLines = 0, .Lines = 0, .Others = 0
                    },
                    Function(x, y)
                        x.Lf += If(y = ControlChars.Cr, 1, 0)
                        x.WhiteSpaces += If(Char.IsSeparator(y), 1, 0)
                        x.Others += If(Not Char.IsWhiteSpace(y), 1, 0)
                        Return x
                    End Function)

    c.NewLines = tbHaveOne.Lines.Count
    c.Lines = SendMessage(tbHaveOne.Handle, EM_GETLINECOUNT, 
                          IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero).ToInt32

    tbHaveTwo.Text = $"WhiteSpaces: {c.WhiteSpaces} Lf: {c.Lf} " +
                        $"New Lines: {c.NewLines} Lines {c.Lines} Others: {c.Others}"

End Sub

Private Sub tbHaveOne_TextChanged(sender As Object, 
                                  e As EventArgs) Handles tbHaveOne.TextChanged
    PrintCounts()
End Sub
```

Please note:

- The `Char.IsSeparator` method is used to get the count of the white spaces since the `Char.IsWhiteSpace` method will return `True` when evaluating; `vbCr`, `vbLf`, `vbCrLf`, `vbTab`, ...etc. Alternatively, you can combine the `Char.IsWhiteSpace` and the `Char.IsControl` methods to evaluate the white spaces. The [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.iswhitespace?view=netcore-3.1#remarks) section has more.
- The `Others` is the count of everything else including the letters, digits, punctuations, symbols...etc. You may wont to examine the other `Char.IsXXX` methods of the [Char](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char?view=netcore-3.1) structure.
- Check out the values of the `Lines` and `NewLines` fields as you type.